# Redirect both directory and files within directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Need to redirect a directory name to one location while directing file paths within that directory to other locations.

In other words:
Redirect /ORIGdirectoryname/ to /Adirectoryname/
Redirect /ORIGdirectoryname/file.php to /Bdirectoryname/

I am finding that if I write:
`redirect 301 /ORIGdirectoryname/ http://yourdomain.com/Adirectoryname/`
`redirect 301 /ORIGdirectoryname/file.php http://yourdomain.com/Bdirectoryname/`

`http://yourdomain.com/ORIGdirectoryname/file.php`
resolves to
`http://yourdomain.com/Adirectoryname/file.php`
when I want it to resolve to
`http://yourdomain.com/Bdirectoryname/`

Comment: Try reversing the order. It's following the first rule and never gets to the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the order it is in.

If you can imagine the timeline of events, it will go:

`/origdirectoryname/(file here)` 301 to `/Adirectoryname/`

Then it won't trigger the second redirect because it's no longer on `origdirectoryname`. If you redirected the file first, it would go:

`/origdirectoryname/file.php` 301 to `/bdirectoryname/`

Then it would not trigger the redirect from `origdirectory` to `adirectory`, as you are now on `bdirectory`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Redirect` directive links two URL path nodes together. To when you have:

```
redirect 301 /ORIGdirectoryname/ http://yourdomain.com/Adirectoryname/
```

You're linking the directory `/ORIGdirectoryname/` to `/Adirectoryname/`, including every file and subdirectory. So going to:

```
http://yourdomain.com/ORIGdirectoryname/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.php
```

will redirect you to:

```
http://yourdomain.com/Adirectoryname/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.php
```

To prevent this, you can use `RedirectMatch` instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ORIGdirectoryname/file.php$ http://yourdomain.com/Bdirectoryname/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ORIGdirectoryname/$ http://yourdomain.com/Adirectoryname/
```

Comment: Didn't try this solution, because reversing the order (as suggested above and below) worked. Thanks!